# How to merge all lists in a dictionary efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary `df2` in which each value is a list of words. Then I would like to merge all these lists into `df3`. To do so, I use a loop, which takes more more than 1 minute to complete.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import twitter_samples
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

df = twitter_samples.strings('tweets.20150430-223406.json')
df2 = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    df2[i] = word_tokenize(df[i])

df3 = []
for i in df2:
    df3 = df3 + df2[i]

df3[0:5]
```

It returns `['RT', '@', 'KirkKus', ':', 'Indirect']`. Could you please a more efficient way to generate `df3` efficiently?

Comment: Could you please show us what output you've got with this code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output data so that we can better understand what you're trying to do here. Also, if your code works and you just want it improved, there is also [codereview.se], but if you post there please read their rules and how-tos to ensure your question is on-topic

Comment: @Saimon I've added the output.

Comment: Why not create `df3` directly from the result of `word_tokenize()` instead of adding to a dict and _then_ adding to a list? Other than that, (and writing it as a list-comprehension which is essentially syntactic sugar) I don't see any more efficient way

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It's because `df2` is a required dataframe in my exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. This should be a bit faster (probably around 1500 times, based on your note that it takes more than 1 minute to complete):

```py
df3 = [v for lst in df2.values() for v in lst]
```

Please let us know how it compares time-wise on your data.

On my system with synthetic data, it takes 35ms to combine 20K lists of 100 words each, resulting in a 2-million long list. By comparison, your code takes 53.5s (1500x slower). Worse: the code you wrote scales super-linearly with `n` (the length of the resulting list): the repeated creation of lists weighs in more and more heavily. In fact, it seems to be roughly `O(k m^2)` based on empirics, for `m` lists of average length `k`.

Final thought: personally I would prefer to have a word count as a result:

```py
from collections import Counter

z = Counter([v for lst in df2.values() for v in lst])
```

and you can make it a smidgen faster using `itertools.chain`:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

z = Counter(chain.from_iterable(df2.values()))
```

Example synthetic setup:

```py
import random

df2 = {i: random.choices(
    'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split(),
    k=100) for i in range(20000)}
```

With that, the counter above takes 140ms and returns (example):

```py
>>> z
Counter({'over': 222301,
         'fox': 222208,
         'the': 445399,
         'lazy': 222688,
         'quick': 221598,
         'dog': 222322,
         'jumps': 221819,
         'brown': 221665})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the values in `df2` are lists, you can simply write the following alternative which is more Pythonic.

```py
df3 = []
for value in df2.values():
    df3.extend(value)
```